# OpenID Connect - Is securing machine-to-machine endpoints allowed?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm currently trying to figure out, if securing machine-to-machine OpenID Connect endpoints besides TLS (for example with basic authentication) is allowed. I refer machine-to-machine endpoints to, for example the token endpoint (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenEndpoint) or the well-known endpoint (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig).

So far I couldn't find anything in the OpenId/OAuth2 specification (i.e https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) on this topic if this is allowed/disallowed/discouraged/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to protect the discovery and the other public endpoints, as they are meant for public consumption by the clients and APIS.

You should always use HTTPS/TLS with the browser because otherwise, you will have problems with the cookies.

For machine-to-machine communication, you have the client credentials flow, which gives you a secure way to establish communication between two services.

How you secure the communication internally on the backend is up to you.

With backend, I mean where the services are hosted:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate `backend` in this context little further. To be honest, I don't get the whole sentence `How you secure the communication internally on the backend is up to you.` Which communication do you mean with `communication internally`?

Comment: With backend, I mean where your services are hosted (cloud, data center...). I added a picture to my answer.

Comment: Also, the discovery and JWKS endpoints does not contain anything sensitive and these are the two main public endpoints that most services interact with. The other endpoints have different authentication needs (client/secret, token....) and if you wan to be compliant, then you should try to follow the spec.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I guessed, but wasn't 100% sure. Appreciate for taking your time.